# How do I clear cookies from the Twitter app internal browser on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, cookies

Just to clarify, I've tried cleaning the Safari cookies with no success.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is anything you can do sans uninstalling and reinstalling the Twitter app.   Each application that uses the WebView has its own cookie store.

A developer can programmatically remove cookies.  So the Twitter app would need to give you a way to clear cookies which I don't think it does.

Answer (score 2):

In the Twitter app, open **Settings and privacy**. As of August 2017 and version 7.4, it is accessed by tapping your profile picture in the top-left corner.

Now go into **Data usage** → **Web storage** and select `Clear all web storage`. This will delete your Twitter cache, cookies and logins.

That action does not affect pictures, videos and vines attached to Tweets. Instead those are deleted under **Data usage** → **Web storage** → `Clear media storage`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to advanced settings under safari.

See twitter weasel's data

Swipe left and delete

Comment: We are talking about clearing the internals of the app, not the web version.